# how to call the url of its api rest symfony with ionic

Tags: angular, api, symfony, ionic-framework

I have developed my api rest in symfony, and do some tests with postman, everything is ok, now i am working on the front part with ionic for the mobile application, and for the authentication part, i would like to know how to use my url login of my api rest. when I test my login form, there is an error in the console that shows me

> POST http://localhost:8100/api/login_check 404 (Not Found)

**Authentication Controller**

```
     /**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED, serializerGroups={"auth-token"})
 * @Rest\Post("/auth-tokens")
 */
public function postAuthTokensAction(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = new Credentials();
    $form = $this->createForm(CredentialsType::class, $credentials);

    $form->submit($request->request->all());

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        return $form;
    }

     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $user = $em->getRepository("DoctixUserBundle:User")
        ->findOneByUsername($credentials->getLogin());

    if (!$user) { // L'utilisateur n'existe pas
        return $this->invalidCredentials();
    }

    $encoder = $this->get('security.password_encoder');
    $isPasswordValid = $encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials->getPassword());

    if (!$isPasswordValid) { // Le mot de passe n'est pas correct
        return $this->invalidCredentials();
    }

    $authToken = new AuthToken();
    $authToken->setValue(base64_encode(random_bytes(50)));
    $authToken->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    $authToken->setUser($user);

    $em->persist($authToken);
    $em->flush();

    return $authToken;
}

private function invalidCredentials()
{
    return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View::create(['message' => 'Invalid credentials'], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

**Ionic Html page**

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-header translucent>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Se Connecter</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content fullscreen>
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ion-list lines="full" class="ion-no-margin ion-no-padding">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="stacked">Nom d'utilisateur  <ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text></ion-label>
      <ion-input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username*" formControlName="username" ></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="stacked">Mot de passe <ion-text color="danger">*</ion-text></ion-label>
      <ion-input required type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password*" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <div class="ion-padding">
    <ion-button size="small" type="submit" class="ion-no-margin" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Se Connecter</ion-button>
    <ion-button size="small" routerLink="/register" routerDirection="forward" class="ion-no-margin">S'inscrire</ion-button>
  </div>
</form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

**Ionic Script controller**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,  FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import {AuthenticationService} from '../authentication/authentication.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  error = '';

  constructor(
      private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
      private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
      private router: Router
  ) {
    this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authenticationService
        .authenticate(this.loginForm.value)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
              localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.token);
              this.router.navigate(['post']);
            },
            error => this.error = error.message
        );
  }
}
```

**My Nelmio Cors config**

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
        forced_allow_origin_value: ~
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['http://localhost:8100']
            allow_headers: ['origin', 'content-type', 'authorization']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
        '^/':
            origin_regex: false
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['origin', 'content-type', 'authorization']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600
            hosts: ['^api\.']
```

**Routing**

This is the routing of the api/login_check in app/config/routing.yml

```
api_login_check:
          path:    /api/login_check
          methods:  [POST, OPTIONS]
```

**Routing for login controller**

```
  api_login:
      path:    /api/login
     defaults: { _controller: "DoctixUserBundle:API\\ApiSecurity:postLogin", _format:json }


authentification:
    path: /api/auth-tokens
    defaults: { _controller: "DoctixUserBundle:API\\ApiSecurity:postAuthTokens", _format:json }
```

**Authentication Service**

```
  export class AuthenticationService {

 constructor(private http: Http) {}
 public apiBase = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';
 authenticate(user: any) {
//   const url     = this.apiBase + 'api/login';
    const body     = new URLSearchParams();
    body.append('username', user.username);
    body.append('password', user.password);
   const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
   const options = new RequestOptions({headers});

  return this.http.post(this.apiBase + 'api/login_check', body.toString(), options).map((data: Response) => data.json() );
    /*.post(url, body.toString(), options)
    .map((data: Response) => data.json());*/
```

}
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be facing a CORS issue.

Have you tried configuring Nelmio CORS correctly?

Configuration file may be something like this:

```
nelmio_cors:
defaults:
    origin_regex: true
    allow_origin: ['%env(CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN)%']
    allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
    allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
    max_age: 3600
paths:
    '^/': ~
```

Where you can change of course the settings you want.

In allow_origin you should put (with this config in the .env file) URLs allowed to use CORS, such as

```
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://(localhost|mydomain.tld)(:[0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: i have applied your suggest, and i have the 404 error not found

Comment: Hello Mohamed, may it be a routing problem now? Do you have the route correctly pointing to the controller you are using? Can you send me the config you have for that? :)

Comment: Hi @DaniPilot, i've just edited in adding the routing that i using. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Mohamed.

Have you defined how to do the login_check in security.yml? How does this exactly work? :)

Comment: Hi @DaniPilot, yes i defined the login_check in security.yml:                     
    `login:
            pattern:    ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                success_handler:                                             
               lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          
               lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure`

Comment: Can you do the post request to /api/login instead of /api/login_check? Does it work that way?

Comment: I try with /api/login and i got this error: ** ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'post' **

Comment: If you do the post request directly (i.e. with postman) does it work?

Comment: did you take a look at my authentication service, maybe there's something wrong ?

Comment: I was thinking so, let me check some stuff to see what could it be :)